# how to disable button ins flutter itsself

Tags: flutter, dart

I have issue to disable the button in its own function when app start button is enable and _enable1=true when I click on it and it should be disable it self but its not working for me

here is my code that i have tried

```
 if(_enable1) {
  resendbutoonfunction=() {
    print("hello");
    setState(() {
      _enable1=false;
      mycolo=Colors.grey;
    });
  //  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) =>disable());
   // _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
  //  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 4), (Timer t) =>timertest());
  };
}
```

here is my button code

```
onPressed:resendbutoonfunction,
```

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to *disable* a button, you need to set it to *null*

```
 resendbutoonfunction() {
        print("hello");
        setState(() {
          _enable1=false;
          mycolo=Colors.grey;
        });
      //  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) =>disable());
       // _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
      //  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 4), (Timer t) =>timertest());
      }
```

Then for your button:

```
onPressed: _enable1 ? resendbutoonfunction : null,
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your code, as you wrote it, the test (if _enable1), and therefore the definition of the function, is executed only once.

Either the test must be inside the function :

```
resendbutoonfunction=() {
 if (_enable1) {
    ...
 }
}
```

Or, if your code is executed regularly, then you can change the definition of resendbutoonfunction

```
if(_enable1) {
  resendbutoonfunction=() {
    print("hello");
    setState(() {
      _enable1=false;
      mycolo=Colors.grey;
    });
  //  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) =>disable());
   // _controller.forward(from: 0.0);
  //  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 4), (Timer t) =>timertest());
  };
}
else {
  resendbutoonfunction=() {
     // do nothing
  }
}
```